# How this logical operator works?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=-10,b=3,c=0,d;
    d= a++||++b &&c++;
    printf("%d %d %d %d ",a,b,c,d);
}
```

How above expression is evaluates. I have read preceedence but still i am getting confused. Kindly give me the right solution of this in step by step.

Comment: [Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) makes it `(a++) || ( (++b) && (c++) )`. The real question is what does pre-increment (`++x`) and post-increment (`x++`) return...

Answer (score 0):

In case of `||` and `&&` operators the order of evaluation is indeed defined as left-to-right.So, operator precedence rules tell you that the grouping should be

```
(a++) || ((++b) && (c++))
```

Now, order-of-evaluation rules tell you that first we evaluate `a++`, then (if necessary) we evaluate `++b`, then (if necessary) we evaluate `c++`, then we evaluate `&&` and finally we evaluate `||`.

Comment: The '(if necessary)' comments sorta mean that the 'then we evaluate `&&` and finally we evaluate `||`' parts are misleading (at best) IMO.  If the `a++` evaluates to non-zero (true), nothing is done with `b` or `c` and the `&&` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is a homework question, so I'll try to give extra explanation. There are actually a lot of concepts going on here!

Here are the main concepts:

1. Pre- and post- increment and decrement. `++a` increments `a` before the value is used in an expression, while `a++` increments `a` after the value is used in the expression.
2. [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Specifically, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, which means that the assignment of `d` should be should be read as `d = (a++) || (++b && c++);`
3. [Expression evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order). The link shows a whole list of evaluation rules for C. In particular, item 2 says (paraphrasing) that for operators `||` and `&&`, the entire left side is always fully evaluated before any evaluation of the right-hand side begins. This is important because of...
4. [Short-circuit boolean evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which says that, for operators `&&` and `||`, if the value of the left-hand term is enough to determine the result of the expression, then the right-hand term is **not evaluated at all**.
5. Behaviour of boolean operators in C. There is no inbuilt boolean type in C, and operators `&&` and `||` work on integer values. In short, an argument is 'true' if it is nonzero, and false if it equals zero. The return value is `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

Putting this all together, here is what happens:

- After the first line, a is -10, b is 3, c is 0 and d is unset.
- Next, the variable `d` needs to be assigned. To determine the value assigned to `d`, the left hand term of `(a++) || (++b && c++)` is evaluated, which is `a++`. The value USED in the expression is 10, however the value of `a` after this expression is -9 due to the post-increment.
- For the purposes of the boolean operator, the value `10` is `true`, and therefore value of the `||` expression is `1`. Because of short-circuit evaluation, this means that `++b && c++` is not evaluated at all, so the increments do not happen. Thus we have `d = 1`.
- At the end, the values are: a = -9, b = 3, c = 0, d = 1.

So the program prints out `-9 3 0 1`.